# grouped pandas DataFrames: how do I apply scipy.stats.sem to them?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, pandas

I know that I can apply numpy methods by doing the following:

`dataList` is a list of `DataFrame`s (same cols/rows).

```
testDF = (concat(dataList, axis=1, keys=range(len(dataList)))
        .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
        .sortlevel(axis=1)
        .groupby(level=0, axis=1))

testDF.aggregate(numpy.mean)
testDF.aggregate(numpy.var)
```

and so on. However, what if I want to compute the standard error of the mean (sem)?

I tried:

```
testDF.aggregate(scipy.stats.sem)
```

but it gave a confusing error. Anyone know how to do this? What are the scipy.stats methods doing differently?

Here's some code that reproduces the error for me:

```
from scipy import stats as st
import pandas
import numpy as np
df_list = []
for ii in range(30):
    df_list.append(pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(600, 10), 
    columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']))

testDF = (pandas.concat(df_list, axis=1, keys=range(len(df_list)))
         .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
         .sortlevel(axis=1)
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1))

testDF.aggregate(st.sem)
```

Here's the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-184cee8fb2ce> in <module>()
     12          .groupby(level=0, axis=1))
     13 
---> 14 testDF.aggregate(st.sem)

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1177                 return self._python_agg_general(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1178             else:
-> 1179                 result = self._aggregate_generic(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1180 
   1181         if not self.as_index:

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _aggregate_generic(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1248             else:
   1249                 result = DataFrame(result, index=obj.index,
-> 1250                                    columns=result_index)
   1251         else:
   1252             result = DataFrame(result)

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    300             mgr = self._init_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    301         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 302             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    303         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    304             mask = ma.getmaskarray(data)

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    389 
    390         # consolidate for now
--> 391         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
    392         return mgr.consolidate()
    393 

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in __init__(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check)
    329 
    330         if do_integrity_check:
--> 331             self._verify_integrity()
    332 
    333     def __nonzero__(self):

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in _verify_integrity(self)
    404         mgr_shape = self.shape
    405         for block in self.blocks:
--> 406             assert(block.values.shape[1:] == mgr_shape[1:])
    407         tot_items = sum(len(x.items) for x in self.blocks)
    408         assert(len(self.items) == tot_items)

AssertionError:
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the actual error message, or even better a small code sample that reproduces the error?  It worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: @DSM: I added the error message to my original question. Note that I'm able to perform numpy methods on this exact same DataFrame without issue.

Comment: I can now reproduce the error, so let's see.. probably my test dataframe was too simple.

Comment: More info: dataList is composed of 30 DataFrames, which are read from csv files (1 csv file = 1 DataFrame). Each csv file has 10 columns and 600 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

It seems that I can replicate this using my work version of the various libraries. I will check my home versions later to see if there is a difference in the docs for these functions.

In the meantime, the following worked for me using your exact edited version:

```
In [35]: testDF.aggregate(lambda x: st.sem(x, axis=None))
Out[35]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 600 entries, 0 to 599
Data columns:
A    600  non-null values
B    600  non-null values
C    600  non-null values
D    600  non-null values
E    600  non-null values
F    600  non-null values
G    600  non-null values
H    600  non-null values
I    600  non-null values
J    600  non-null values
dtypes: float64(10)
```

This makes me suspect that it has to do with the `sem()` axis conventions. It defaults to 0, and the Pandas objects that this ultimately gets mapped to might have a weird 0-th axis or something. When I used the option `axis=None`, it ravels the object that it gets applied to, and this made it work.

Just as a sanity check, I did this and it worked too:

```
In [37]: testDF.aggregate(lambda x: st.sem(x, axis=1))
Out[37]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 600 entries, 0 to 599
Data columns:
A    600  non-null values
B    600  non-null values
C    600  non-null values
D    600  non-null values
E    600  non-null values
F    600  non-null values
G    600  non-null values
H    600  non-null values
I    600  non-null values
J    600  non-null values
dtypes: float64(10)
```

**But you should check to make sure this is actually the SEM values you wanted,** probably on some smaller example data.

**Older answer:**
Could this have to do with module issues with scipy.stats? When I use this module, I have to call it as `from scipy import stats as st` or something like that. `import scipy.stats` doesn't work, and calling `import scipy; scipy.stats.sem` gives an error saying that no module named "stats" exists.

Pandas appears to simply not be finding that function. I think the error messages should be improved because this is not obvious.

```
>>> from scipy import stats as st
>>> import pandas
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df_list = []
>>> for ii in range(10):
...     df_list.append(pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), 
...     columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']))
... 
>>> df_list
# Suppressed the output cause it was big.

>>> testDF = (pandas.concat(df_list, axis=1, keys=range(len(df_list)))
...     .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
...     .sortlevel(axis=1)
...     .groupby(level=0, axis=1))
>>> testDF
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x38524d0>
>>> testDF.aggregate(np.mean)
key_0         A         B         C
0      0.660324  0.408377  0.374681
1      0.459768  0.345093  0.432542
2      0.498985  0.443794  0.524327
3      0.605572  0.563768  0.558702
4      0.561849  0.488395  0.592399
5      0.466505  0.433560  0.408804
6      0.561591  0.630218  0.543970
7      0.423443  0.413819  0.486188
8      0.514279  0.479214  0.534309
9      0.479820  0.506666  0.449543
>>> testDF.aggregate(np.var)
key_0         A         B         C
0      0.093908  0.095746  0.055405
1      0.075834  0.077010  0.053406
2      0.094680  0.092272  0.095552
3      0.105740  0.126101  0.099316
4      0.087073  0.087461  0.111522
5      0.105696  0.110915  0.096959
6      0.082860  0.026521  0.075242
7      0.100512  0.051899  0.060778
8      0.105198  0.100027  0.097651
9      0.082184  0.060460  0.121344
>>> testDF.aggregate(st.sem)
          A         B         C
0  0.089278  0.087590  0.095891
1  0.088552  0.081365  0.098071
2  0.087968  0.116361  0.076837
3  0.110369  0.087563  0.096460
4  0.101328  0.111676  0.046567
5  0.085044  0.099631  0.091284
6  0.113337  0.076880  0.097620
7  0.087243  0.087664  0.118925
8  0.080569  0.068447  0.106481
9  0.110658  0.071082  0.084928
```

Seems to work for me.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I have a bad install or something. I edited my original question with a version of your code that reproduces the error for me (and is more representative of my dataset).

Comment: The first AssertionError in your code suggests you're not running the edited version that you posted. It's choking on the line, `79 test = testDF.aggregate(sp.stats.sem)`, which looks like your old issue... importing just SciPy then trying to use scipy.stats.sem, which won't work. Can you figure out why it's showing us an error for the code `test = testDF.aggregate(sp.stats.sem)` instead of the newly edited version which does not involve importing SciPy that way? I suspect you're running the wrong version of your edit or something.

Comment: I edited with something that seems to work. It looks like this is an issue with a new version of `sem()` that has different default axis conventions than the older version. My guess now is that whatever Pandas slice/group thing that gets hit by the `aggregate()` function has a bad (maybe singleton or something) 0-th dimension and the array needs to be flattened for it to work.

Comment: That was it! I checked it against my data and the axis=1 method correctly computes `sem()`. Oddly, the results of the method I used before to compute sem, `std / sqrt(# replicates)`, varies _slightly_ from `sem()` results, but we're only talking ~4e-11 difference max. I'm guessing it's rounding. Thanks mate.